# Python pandas Can I calculate the delta of column values by the ID of another column in minute increments?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Csv file that looks something like this

| Time | Count | Operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:01:00 | 2 | Up |
| 10:01:00 | 5 | Down |
| 10:01:00 | 1 | Down |
| 10:01:00 | 2 | Up |
| 10:01:00 | 1 | Up |
| 10:02:00 | 3 | Down |
| 10:02:00 | 2 | Up |
| 10:02:00 | 5 | Down |

I want to add up the values of the count column for each minute by the id of the operations column and then for the same minute subtract the up and down sums from each other which should give me something like this

`Sum()`:

| Time | Count | Operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:01:00 | 5 | Up |
| 10:01:00 | 6 | Down |
| 10:02:00 | 2 | Up |
| 10:02:00 | 8 | Down |

`Diff()`:

| Time | Delta |
| --- | --- |
| 10:01:00 | 1 |
| 10:02:00 | 6 |

To do this, I try something like

```
def Delta_Volume():
    df = pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv, usecols=['Time','Count','Operation'], parse_dates=[0])
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.floor("T", 0).dt.time
    df1 = df.groupby('Operation').sum('Count')
    df2 = df.groupby('Operation').diff('Count')
    #df['Delt_of_row'] = df.loc[1 : 3,['Count' , 'Operation']].sum(axis = 1)
    #df['Delt_of_row'] = df.loc[1 : 3,['Count' , 'Operation']].diff(axis = 1)
    print(df1)
```

But it doesn't work the way I need unfortunately

Comment: Warm Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a classical [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), then use the MultiIndex to compute the difference:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Operation', 'Time']).sum()
print(df2)

out = df2.loc['Down']-df2.loc['Up']
print(out)
```

output:

```
# groupby.sum
                    Count
Operation Time           
Down      10:01:00      6
          10:02:00      8
Up        10:01:00      5
          10:02:00      2

# difference
          Count
Time           
10:01:00      1
10:02:00      6
```

Comment: You have once again solved most of my problems with mozway formulas

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.Count.diff(-1).head(1)

df1.groupby(['Time','Operation'],as_index=False).sum()\
    .groupby('Time').apply(function1).droplevel(1)
```

out

```
          Count
Time           
10:01:00      1
10:02:00      6
```